# Execute Stored Procedure multiple times using Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I want Dapper to execute a Stored Procedure once for every item's parameters.

I am looping the collection to build parameters. And I don't want to place the execute method inside the loop.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
public static int SaveData3() 
        {
            var list = new List<Person>();
            var p1 = new Person() { Id = 20, FirstName = "Michiel", LastName = "De Ruyter" };
            var p2 = new Person() { Id = 21, FirstName = "Jacob", LastName = "Jakobsson" };
            list.Add(p1);
            list.Add(p2);

            var queryParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                queryParameters.Add("@id", item.Id);
                Log.Information("added {0} as parameter", item.Id);
                queryParameters.Add("@first_name", item.FirstName);
                Log.Information("added {0} as parameter", item.FirstName);
                queryParameters.Add("@last_name", item.LastName);
                Log.Information("added {0} as parameter", item.LastName);
            }

            using (IDbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    var affectedRows = connection.Execute("kwc_test_person_procedure",
                    queryParameters,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    );
                    Log.Information("Executed procedure to store data. Rows affected: {0}", affectedRows);
                    return affectedRows;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex.Message);
                    Log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
```

When I ran this, only the last object (Jacob) is stored in the database.

> 2021-06-22 13:52:58.225 +02:00 [INF] added 20 as parameter
> 2021-06-22 13:52:58.287 +02:00 [INF] added Michiel as parameter
> 2021-06-22 13:52:58.291 +02:00 [INF] added De Ruyter as parameter
> 2021-06-22 13:52:58.293 +02:00 [INF] added 21 as parameter 2021-06-22
> 13:52:58.296 +02:00 [INF] added Jacob as parameter 2021-06-22
> 13:52:58.299 +02:00 [INF] added Jakobsson as parameter 2021-06-22
> 13:52:58.817 +02:00 [INF] Executed procedure to store data. Rows
> affected: 1

I have also tried to follow the "Many" example from:
https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute#example---execute-stored-procedure

```
try
                {
                    var persons = new Person[] {
                    new Person {Id= 41, FirstName = "homeless", LastName="dude"},
                    new Person {Id= 42, FirstName = "hungry", LastName="person"}
                };

                    int rowsAffected = connection.Execute("kwc_test_person_procedure", persons, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    Log.Information("Executed procedure to store data. Rows affected: {0}", rowsAffected);
                    return rowsAffected;
                }
```

But then I get:

> ORA-06550 PLS-00306 (wrong number or types of arguments in call ...)

Comment: You can't have multiple parameters with the same name. Either execute the procedure on every run, or change it to accept a list/table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using stored procedures, Dapper can't see the signature, so it assumes that all reachable members should be added. I'm guessing that `Person` has *other* properties, which is causing this failure.

try, then:

```cs
int rowsAffected = connection.Execute("kwc_test_person_procedure",
    persons.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.FirstName, x.LastName }),
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This creates a per-person projection of *just* the `Id`, `FirstName` and `LastName` which (it seems) should match the stored procedure parameters. You can also use this approach to give them different names, if needed, for example:

```cs
    persons.Select(x => new { id = x.Id, fName = x.FirstName, lName = x.LastName }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
The Person class actually only contains those 3 mentioned properties.
And I have tried the per-person projection, but it still complains about wrong number or type of arguments.

Comment: @KWC ok; what parameters does the stored procedure declare? can we see that?

Comment: Have you tried removing the @'s in front of the parameter name? They don't need to be there and as far as I know Oracle uses :'s anyway.

Comment: @MarcGravell, the signature of the procedure is like the following:
kwc_test_person_procedure(
id in number,
first_name in varchar2,
last_name in varchar2
)

Comment: @KWC then you need `persons.Select(x => new { id = x.Id, first_name = x.FirstName, last_name = x.LastName })`, like I hinted at in the last line of my answer (but obviously with the actual parameter names)

Comment: @MarcGravell, sorry that I overlooked it. I tried your suggestion and can confirm that this worked! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @PalleDue, No I haven't tried that. Thanks for the reply. The suggestion from Marc worked. :)